# Translate excel formulas into SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I am looking for help to translate excel formulas into SQL (Oracle).
With given fixed input values for rows 1 (Month ascending) and 2 (SU - some number).  I have to calculate through particular cells to get value for D8.

[image]

Complexity is, that formulas reference values in recurring levels/previous column/earlier months

Let me provide calculations for one column, as an example let's take column D

```
D1 - Month
D2 - SU 
D3 - C7 
D4 - C4 + B7
D5 - D3 * 1.54 + D4
D6 - D2 - D5
D7 - D6 / 2.38
D8 - D3 + D4 + D7
```

Below queries to build and populate exemplary table and populate it with data.

```
  CREATE TABLE TESTOSS
   (    PERIOD_MONTH VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    SU NUMBER
   );
   
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2020-09',503);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2020-10',1109);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2020-11',1537);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2020-12',2327);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-01',3000);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-02',4000);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-03',5000);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-04',3292);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-05',3721);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-06',4149);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-07',4578);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-08',5006);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-09',5435);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-10',5863);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-11',6292);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-12',6720);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2022-02',7577);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2022-01',7149);
```

Does anybody got any clue how to tackle this one?

Comment: Please,  describe what `c4`, `c7` and so on are. If you may describe the formula in terms of dimension values (what does `T1` or `T2` mean?) and periods, then please provide this description. Unfortunately, we do not know the meaning of your cells and SQL table doesn't have cells also. Generally it is possible if you unpivot the data to have month, some dimension (which is `SU` and so on) and measure value and create a formula in this terms along with the desired output

Comment: Columns C4 and C7 are respectively calculated as provided above:  
C4 will be B4 + A7  
and  
C7 will be B6 / 2.38  
All rows have the same calculation, T1 and T2 are just labels, transponsed (unpivoted) they turn into column names

Comment: Well... If `C4 = B4 + A7` then I cannot add `'NP'` (string) to a zero (number).

Comment: @astentx None of the values being calculated are strings or use strings in their calculations. Everything is calculated from the `SU` column.

Comment: @MT0 Can you please clarify the formula? As I understand, those C, D etc are spreadsheet cells. Then A7 is equal to `'NP'`

Comment: @astentx See my answer below, it has all the formulae in it (and is identical to the OP's calculations in the spreadsheet that they state for column `D`). The `A` column in the spreadsheet is a header column and does not contain data; the data starts from the "dummy row" in column `B`.

Comment: Month (row1) and SU (row2) are provided base values for this calculation, using those it is possible to calculate TPE(row8) and that is the solution I am looking for..

Comment: @MT0 Thank you very much, now I've understood the offsetting mechanism. My vote for this great solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY period_month) AS rn
  FROM TESTOSS t
)
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES (
    period_month, SU, 0 AS t1, 0 AS t2, 0 AS rp_su, 0 AS n_su, 0 AS np, 0 AS tpe
  )
  RULES AUTOMATIC ORDER (
    t1[rn>1]  = np[cv(rn)-1],
    t2[rn>2]  = t2[cv(rn)-1] + np[cv(rn)-2],
    rp_su[rn] = t1[cv(rn)] * 1.54 + t2[cv(rn)],
    n_su[rn]  = su[cv(rn)] - rp_su[cv(rn)],
    np[rn]    = n_su[cv(rn)] / 2.38,
    tpe[rn]   = t1[cv(rn)] + t2[cv(rn)] + np[cv(rn)]
  )
order by rn;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | RN | PERIOD_MONTH | SU | T1 | T2 | RP_SU | N_SU | NP | TPE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2020-09 | 503 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 503 | 211.344537815126050420168067226890756303 | 211.344537815126050420168067226890756303 |
> | 2 | 2020-10 | 1109 | 211.344537815126050420168067226890756303 | 0 | 325.470588235294117647058823529411764707 | 783.529411764705882352941176470588235293 | 329.214038556599110232328225407810182896 | 540.558576371725160652496292634700939199 |
> | 3 | 2020-11 | 1537 | 329.214038556599110232328225407810182896 | 211.344537815126050420168067226890756303 | 718.334157192288680177953534354918437963 | 818.665842807711319822046465645081562037 | 343.977244877189630177330447750034269763 | 884.535821248914790829826740384735208962 |
> | 4 | 2020-12 | 2327 | 343.977244877189630177330447750034269763 | 540.558576371725160652496292634700939199 | 1070.283533482597191125585182169753714634 | 1256.716466517402808874414817830246285366 | 528.032128788824709611098662953884993851 | 1412.567950037739500440925403338620202813 |
> | 5 | 2021-01 | 3000 | 528.032128788824709611098662953884993851 | 884.535821248914790829826740384735208962 | 1697.705299583704843630918681333718099493 | 1302.294700416295156369081318666281900507 | 547.182647233737460659277864985832731305 | 1959.750597271476961100203268324452934118 |
> | 6 | 2021-02 | 4000 | 547.182647233737460659277864985832731305 | 1412.567950037739500440925403338620202813 | 2255.229226777695189856213315416802609023 | 1744.770773222304810143786684583197390977 | 733.096963538783533673859951505545122259 | 2692.847560810260494774063219829998056377 |
> | 7 | 2021-03 | 5000 | 733.096963538783533673859951505545122259 | 1959.750597271476961100203268324452934118 | 3088.719921121203602957947593642992422397 | 1911.280078878796397042052406357007577603 | 803.058856671763192034475800990339318321 | 3495.906417482023686808539020820337374698 |
> | 8 | 2021-04 | 3292 | 803.058856671763192034475800990339318321 | 2692.847560810260494774063219829998056377 | 3929.558200084775810507155953355120606591 | -637.558200084775810507155953355120606591 | -267.881596674275550633258803930722943946 | 3228.024820807748136175280216889614430752 |
> | 9 | 2021-05 | 3721 | -267.881596674275550633258803930722943946 | 3495.906417482023686808539020820337374698 | 3083.368758603639338833320462767024041021 | 637.631241396360661166679537232975958979 | 267.912286300991874439781318165115949151 | 3495.937107108740010615061535054730379903 |
> | 10 | 2021-06 | 4149 | 267.912286300991874439781318165115949151 | 3228.024820807748136175280216889614430752 | 3640.609741711275622812543446863892992445 | 508.390258288724377187456553136107007555 | 213.609352222153099658595190393322272082 | 3709.546459330893110273656725448052651985 |
> | 11 | 2021-07 | 4578 | 213.609352222153099658595190393322272082 | 3495.937107108740010615061535054730379903 | 3824.895509530855784089298128260446678909 | 753.104490469144215910701871739553321091 | 316.430458180312695760799105772921563484 | 4025.976917511205806034455831220974215469 |
> | 12 | 2021-08 | 5006 | 316.430458180312695760799105772921563484 | 3709.546459330893110273656725448052651985 | 4196.84936492857466174528734833835185975 | 809.15063507142533825471265166164814025 | 339.979258433371990863324643555314344643 | 4365.956175944577796897780474776288560112 |
> | 13 | 2021-09 | 5435 | 339.979258433371990863324643555314344643 | 4025.976917511205806034455831220974215469 | 4549.544975498598671963975782296158306219 | 885.455024501401328036024217703841693781 | 372.03992626109299497311941920329482932 | 4737.996102205670791870899893979583389432 |
> | 14 | 2021-10 | 5863 | 372.03992626109299497311941920329482932 | 4365.956175944577796897780474776288560112 | 4938.897662386661009156384380349362597265 | 924.102337613338990843615619650637402735 | 388.278293114848315480510764559091345687 | 5126.274395320519107351410658538674735119 |
> | 15 | 2021-11 | 6292 | 388.278293114848315480510764559091345687 | 4737.996102205670791870899893979583389432 | 5335.94467360253719771088647140058406179 | 956.05532639746280228911352859941593821 | 401.70391865439613541559391957958652866 | 5527.978313974915242767004578118261263779 |
> | 16 | 2021-12 | 6720 | 401.70391865439613541559391957958652866 | 5126.274395320519107351410658538674735119 | 5744.898430048289155891425294691237989255 | 975.101569951710844108574705308762010745 | 409.706541996517161390157439205362189389 | 5937.684855971432404157162017323623453168 |
> | 17 | 2022-01 | 7149 | 409.706541996517161390157439205362189389 | 5527.978313974915242767004578118261263779 | 6158.926388649551671307847034494519035438 | 990.073611350448328692152965505480964562 | 415.99731569346568432443401911994998511 | 6353.682171664898088481596036443573438278 |
> | 18 | 2022-02 | 7577 | 415.99731569346568432443401911994998511 | 5937.684855971432404157162017323623453168 | 6578.320722139369558016790406768346430237 | 998.679277860630441983209593231653569763 | 419.61314195824808486689478707212334864 | 6773.295313623146173348490823515696786918 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fbc941ccfef730aac897bd96546e1ea0)*

Comment: Brilliant! 
Magnificient! May the universe shine on you! (: Kudos!

Comment: @Kondjitsu If this answer provided the solution for your issue in question (I think it did), then you may accept it to signify that you've got what you want.